# If statement to choose a value

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the following code:

```
If Numcolyo = Even Then
    .StartPoint.y = BuWidth / 2 + ccFacoy
    Else
    .StartPoint.y = BuWidth / 2
    End If
```

But it doesn't do what I expect it to do. The code works though. Say for example if `Numcolyo=4` then I want the first statement to be true: `StartPoint.y = BuWidth / 2 + ccFacoy`

If `Numcolyo=3` then I want the second statement to be true: `StartPoint.y = BuWidth / 2`

Have I written anything wrong? Thankful for any kind of help :)

Comment: Tip: Always use Option Explicit at the top of your code. That forces you to declare all your variables. That way, you could've spotted that Even is not a keyword in VBA.

Comment: Hi Haris, how can I write that into my code? I'm new to VBA programming. Thank you.

Comment: @Haris. Sorry now i understand what you meant, I will do that next time :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think there is an EVEN keyword in VBA.  Try it with the modulus operator which returns the remainder of a division operation:

```
If Numcolyo Mod 2 = 0  Then
    .StartPoint.y = BuWidth / 2 + ccFacoy
Else
    .StartPoint.y = BuWidth / 2
End If
```

When something divided by 2 has no remainder, it is even.

Comment: There is an EVEN method in Excel VBA, so I was wrong, in a sense.  But I don't think that's what you wanted to implement.

Comment: Hi VBlades, your solution with the **Mod 2 = 0** worked very good. Thank you for your help. I will post the solution after 8 hours since my rep wont allow me at the moment. Again, thank you.